# Excel formula to separate numbers with comma from cell

Tags: excel, formula

I have a logical problem to get numbers out of text. I have "4 hours 41 mins" in A1. Ideally it would be nice to have as an output 4,41. However I will be satisfied with 4 and 41 in different cells that I can connect by another formula.

I have tried with `=LEFT(A1;(FIND(" ";A1;1)-1))` and I am getting 4. But there is no success with `=RIGHT(A1;(FIND(" ";A1;1)+5))` (getting "41 mins").

Comment: Is the text always in the format of "x hours yy mins" ?

Comment: Good question! No it can be "11 hours 2 mins".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pattern is as you say then:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," mins","")," hours ",",")
```

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q68;" mins";"");" hours";",")` outputs "4, 41" with unnecessary space between 4, and 41